# Fetch multiple records from single query

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Hello people here is my query

```
UPDATE `talent2db`.`talent_employee` SET `Rec_Status` = 'I' WHERE `talent_employee`.`Emp_Id` = '241074' AND `talent_employee`.`Rec_Status` = 'A' ;

UPDATE `talent2db`.`talent_employee` SET `Rec_Status` = 'I' WHERE `talent_employee`.`Emp_Id` = '785062' AND `talent_employee`.`Rec_Status` = 'A' ;
```

BY USING ABOVE QUERY IAM TRYING TO set "rec_status" to 'I' from 'A',as we can see we are trying to update for two employess with two different emp_ids... is it possible to update by writing only one query ...?? it should be something like

```
UPDATE `talent2db`.`talent_employee` SET `Rec_Status` = 'I' WHERE `talent_employee`.`Emp_Id` = '785062,241074' AND `talent_employee`.`Rec_Status` = 'A' ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `IN` clause.

```
UPDATE `talent2db`.`talent_employee` 
SET `Rec_Status` = 'I' 
WHERE `talent_employee`.`Emp_Id` IN ('785062','241074') AND 
      `talent_employee`.`Rec_Status` = 'A' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use condtion like this (`talent_employee`.`Emp_Id` = '785062,241074' OR `talent_employee`.`Emp_Id` = '785062')

following is the actual query

```
UPDATE `talent2db`.`talent_employee` SET `Rec_Status` = 'I' WHERE (`talent_employee`.`Emp_Id` = '785062,241074' OR `talent_employee`.`Emp_Id` = '785062') AND `talent_employee`.`Rec_Status` = 'A' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `OR` clause.

```
UPDATE `talent2db`.`talent_employee` 
SET    `rec_status` = 'I' 
WHERE  (`talent_employee`.`emp_id` = '785062' OR `talent_employee`.`emp_id` = '241074') 
AND `talent_employee`.`rec_status` = 'A';
```